# How to handle form submission in svelte/sapper?

Tags: svelte, sapper

If form data is split into multiple pages, how to pass data of form submission from one page to another.

Comment: You could put the data in Context and have the other pages get it from Context. Your question body seems pretty different from the question title; which question are you asking?